# Replace placeholders with curly braces in Route Attribute with actual values in Swagger documentation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger

We have an ASP.NET Core MVC controller that is decorated with following attribute:

```
[Route("api/v{version}/[controller]
class MyController
{ }
```

We have integrated Swagger using Swashbuckle and use SwaggerUI for API docs.

The API docs in swagger shows the following route:

```
/api/v{version}/MyController/MyAction
```

We would like to replace the {version} with the respective version value in the SwaggerUI.

Expected output:

```
/api/v1/MyController/MyAction --> when viewing docs of v1
/api/v2/MyController/MyAction --> when viewing docs of v2**
```

I tried implementing `ISchemaFilter` & `IOperationFilter` but could not find a place where I can modify this.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by implement `IDocumentFilter`. You could try following:
package `Asp.Versioning.Mvc`
Controller

```
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("Test")]
        [ApiVersion("1")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]
        public IActionResult Test1()
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet("Test")]
        [ApiVersion("2")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]
        public IActionResult Test2()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

DocFilter.cs

```
    public class DocFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            var oldpaths = swaggerDoc.Paths;

            swaggerDoc.Paths = new OpenApiPaths(); //clear old paths

            foreach (var path in oldpaths)
            {
                var key = path.Key.Replace("v{version}", swaggerDoc.Info.Version);

                var value = path.Value;

                swaggerDoc.Paths.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
...
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo{ Version = "v1"});
    options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo{ Version = "v2"});
    options.DocumentFilter<DocFilter>();
});
...
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RouteTemplate = "api/docs/{documentName}/docs.json";
});
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/api/docs/v1/docs.json", "v1");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/api/docs/v2/docs.json", "v2");
});
```

Test
[image]
[image]